# How to convert to Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.6

I am in the process of converting Python 2 code into Python 3. Currently I am facing difficulty in converting the following code to Python 3. Please help.

```
print 'Data cache hit ratio: %4.2f%%' % ratio
```

Also, what %4.2f%% means?

Tried to rewrite the code with format().

Comment: the only part of this that wont work in python 3 is that you dont have parenthesis around the string% var ... `print(...)` and it will just work ...

Answer (score 1):

Just put parens around the parameters.

```
print('Data cache hit ratio: %4.2f%%' % ratio)
```

There are fancier ways of doing formatting in Python 3, but that will work.

`%4.2f` says "display this floating point number in a 4-character field with a decimal point and two places after.  So, like "9.99".  `%%` says "display a percent sign".  The formatting here is straight from the C printf function.

Answer (score 1):

f denotes the fixed point notation. The value that precedes with % (4.2) is for denoting the width (4) and the precision (2) of the number respectively.

You can use either .format or f string

`print("Floating point {0:4.2f}".format(ratio))`

`print(f' Floating point {ratio:4.2f}')`

Here 4 is the total width of the field being printed, lefted-padded by spaces. 2 is the number of digits after the decimal point. You can read more about it here https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language